# Parallel For Each with a Thread.Sleep

Tags: multithreading

Basicly, i want to access a lot of pages from the same URl, but i don't wan't to spam it at the same secound.And i wan't it over in 30minutes.
Does the Thread.Sleep() inside the parallel works fine?
Because only after like 90 minutes i have it done.

```
        var pages = new List<string>( urls );
        var sources = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        string htmlCode = "";

        Random randomN = new Random();

        Parallel.ForEach(pages, x =>
        {
            x = x.Replace("//", "http://");
            int sleep = randomN.Next(0, 1800000);
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);

            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(x);
            newRequest.Timeout = 15000;
            newRequest.Proxy = null;
            newRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
            newRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit / 537.11(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 23.0.1300.0 Iron / 23.0.1300.0 Safari / 537.11";
            newRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)newRequest.GetResponse();
            htmlCode = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)).ReadToEnd();
            sources.Add(htmlCode);

        });

        return sources;
```

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is not very clear, though, as to what you are trying to achieve. But Thread.Sleep in parallel.foreach might not be the right option. Try going thru the below threads, they might be helpful and solve your issue.

[1]. [Parallel.ForEach using Thread.Sleep equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462525/parallel-foreach-using-thread-sleep-equivalent)

[2]. [Thread.Sleep blocking parallel execution of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561196/thread-sleep-blocking-parallel-execution-of-tasks)

[3]. [Parallel ForEach wait 500 ms before spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655427/parallel-foreach-wait-500-ms-before-spawning)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to sleep inside your Parallel.ForEach body--that'll just tie up the worker threads in the .NET thread pool.

This is what [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx) is for. Just create a bunch of delayed tasks and then do a [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) on them.

Comment: Oh, and an unrelated tip: Never use a single System.Random instance inside a Parallel.ForEach body... it isn't thread-safe and will break horribly (starts returning nothing but zero). See this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx) for workarounds.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach also blocks the thread, so it is good only for front-end apps or tests, and not for back-end server that need to run a lot of Parallel.ForEach flows in parallel.

Comment: Wait, what? 
@jenkas, can you give us some more info about it? What should we use instead of Parallel.ForEach for background tasks?

Comment: @DavideBellone Sure, use Parallel.ForEachAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0. Do not forget to "await" it, so it will suspend flow without blocking thread